# Show dialog if application is in the background

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a class that shows dialogs at various stages of the application. But if the application is in the background, and at that moment it's time to show the dialogue, then this is a problem. After moving to the foreground, the dialog itself is not displayed, the screen has a background background and the activity is not responsive.
For example, this situation occurs when the download is complete and my dialog is displayed, and the device has switched to screen lock mode.
So far, I only know one solution. Track the background state of the app in every activity. If the application is in the background, you need to pass the display of the dialog to the `OnResume()` and `OnStart()` methods. But this is not the most elegant option, especially if the application has many activities and you need to display dialogs in all activities.
Is there a better solution?
P.S.
My very simplified dialog output class.

```
class MyAplication : AppCompatActivity
{
    Action WaitForeground;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            await LoadFile();
            
            if (!IsBackground) MyCustomDialog.ShowInfoDialog(this);
            else
            {
                WaitForeground = ()=> { MyCustomDialog.ShowInfoDialog(this);};
            }
        });
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        WaitForeground?.Invoke();
        WaitForeground = null;
    }
}

public class MyCustomDialog : Dialog
{
    private int id;
    public MyCustomDialog(Activity activity, int id) : base(activity)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestWindowFeature((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(id, null));
    }
    public static void ShowInfoDialog(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            new MyCustomDialog(activity, Resource.Layout.dialog_Info).Show();
        });
    }
    public static void ShowAskDialog(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            new MyCustomDialog(activity, Resource.Layout.dialog_Ask).Show();
        });
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

Comment: You just need to pass the dialogs to the current activity (the one that display) . As only the life cycle event of the current activity will been called when app transform between background and foreground .

Comment: I do not understand what it is about.
I started the task, and during execution, my application faded into the background. The task is completed, and the `UI thread` shows a dialogue. But after moving the application to the foreground, there is no dialogue. Even within the same activity. It turns out that you cannot call `Dialog.Show()` until the application returns to the foreground?

Comment: We can only push toast  when app in background .